# Is regular rent also paid with the "advance to utility" chance card?

Tags: monopoly

Two utilities are owned by a player. Another player lands on chance and the chance card directs the player to pay ten times the role of the dice to the utilities owner. Is the player also obligated to pay "rent" for landing on the utility in addition to the payment indicated on the chance card?

The card says:

> Advance token to nearest Utility. If unowned, you may buy it from the Bank. If owned, throw dice and pay owner a total ten times the amount thrown

Comment: what rules is this? From my understanding it is 4x  for one owned and 10x for both

Comment: What is full text of Chance card?  I've not played this for years (thankfully!) but I'm aware of cards asking players to pay money or asking players to "advance to...." but not both.

Comment: @StartPlayer I added the text

Comment: I am still unclear as to where you are getting 19x from.

Comment: @JoeW I assume that was just a typo for 10.  I've edited it out.

Comment: Furthermore, you should pay the amount even if the property is mortgaged. The card mentions neither rent, as do the cards that send you to railroads, nor the property's mortgage state The card simply states that, if the property is owned, you should throw the dice and pay 10 times the amount. So, you should pay the amount, even if the property is mortgaged.

Answer (score 4):

Do what is written on the card.

> Advance token to nearest Utility. If unowned, you may buy it from the Bank. If owned, throw dice and pay owner a total 10 times the amount thrown.

The card does move the player without a roll and demands a **specific** payment to a **specified** player, altering normal behavior. So **just** the alternate, always x10, payment from the roll.

Answer (score 3):

You pay rent exactly once for the utilities when moving with the chance card.

First, the chance card text is clearly intended as a replacement effect for the rent you would normally pay.  The evidence for this is the use of the word "total" to indicate the amount that you pay, and the parallel language to the railroad chance card, which says:

> Advance token to the nearest Railroad and pay owner twice the rental to which he/she is otherwise entitled. If Railroad is unowned, you may buy it from the Bank.

Second, the utilities charge you rent based on the roll that brought you to them.  In this case, you didn't make a roll to get to the utility in question (you were moved by a chance card), so the rent you would pay based on your movement is 0.

Thus, the only rent you pay is for the roll you make because of the chance card.